# How do I change decimal variable to hexadecimal variable in C?

Tags: c, hex, decimal

I want to convert decimal to hexadecimal.

To better understand, the variable could be as follows:

100(decimal) → 100(hexadecimal)

99999(decimal) → 99999(hexadecimal)

Comment: What do you mean? `100 != 0x100`.

Comment: What is the variable type?

Comment: wanna make 0x100 from 100 and so on?

Comment: `printf("%d -> 0x%d" , 100 , 100);:`

Comment: When int x is 99999(decimal value), I want to be x = 629145(decimal value).

Comment: And I do not want to use the 0x.

Comment: That's an odd thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    long dec = strtol(argv[1], 0, 10);
    long hex = strtol(argv[1], 0, 16);
    printf("%ld -> %ld (hex %lx)\n", dec, hex, hex);
    return 0;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ gcc -o nohmi nohmi.c
$ ./nohmi 100
100 -> 256 (hex 100)
$
```